# Read a word from a file and store the value next to it in c

Tags: c, file

I am writing a program in C where i have a text file with the following contents:

*City- 12*

*Temp- 78*

*Info1- blahblah blahblah*

*Info2- blahblah blahblah*

Now i want to read the file line by line and after the first word (e.g "City-" )read the value next to it until i find the next *interesting* word (Info1, Temp) etc. My code looks like this so far:

```
    File * fp;
    char * buf[1024];
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s[^-]s", buf) ==1){
      if(buf == "City-"){
       /*Do something here and read until you find next interesting word */
      }
     }
```

Now, i know that this is pretty simple but i have trouble understanding how to procceed after i have read the first word. Thanks!

Comment: `%s[^-]s` is wrong, you mean `%[^-]-` which will read the non-hyphen characters into the string and then consume the `-`. Or `%s` which will read a space-delimited word.  Strings are compared with `strcmp`. Or perhaps you'd want to use. The `char *buf[1024]` is incorrect too, you want `char buf[1024]`.

Comment: You are right, i am actually using strcmp to compare strings an d i guess i got carried away here. But still, i dont' get how can i read the word that comes after the "-" and store it somewhere.

Comment: the same way that you read the `City-`. The file pointer is advanced to the space character following `-`.

Comment: I see. I will give it a shot. Thank you for your help!